# Trying to extract file icons and use as a sprite texture

Tags: unity, textures

I'm trying to extract file icons from the files inside a folder (eg: Program Files), and have them set as my Sprite's texture. I extracted the file icons, converted them to Bitmaps and then to byte array, and call the LoadImage(byte[] byte) function in my Sprite object. But when I test, the textures become the image belows. Any idea how to fix this? I just want to set my sprites texture as the extracted file icon, I'm creating something similar to a file explorer.

this is the result that i get

[image]

this is what I should get if I navigate to the notepad++ folder (eg : "C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\")

[image]

this is my settings for the texture (supposedly, later being replaced with the extracted icons)
[image]

Here's my code

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Image targetImg;
public void Load(string directory) 
{
    Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(directory);
    Bitmap bmp = icon.ToBitmap();
    targetImg.sprite.texture.LoadImage(ImageToByte(bmp));
}

public static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Comment: Can you post on what they are meant to look like?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, for accessing bitmap's pixel data, you should use LockBits() function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this:

```
var bitmapData = scaledBitmap.LockBits(...);
var length = bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height;
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
// load image
targetImg.sprite.texture.LoadImage(ImageToByte(bmp));
scaledBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```